# Are there any x86 security Linux distributions based on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, security, distributions

Are there any x86 security distributions like Kali Linux or better them based on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The [DistroWatch.com search](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?category=Security&basedon=Ubuntu) allows for filtering distributions by “Distribution category”, one being “Security”, as well as descendance (“Based on”). The search yields the following three results:

- [BackBox Linux](https://distrowatch.com/backbox) (https://www.backbox.org)
  BackBox Linux is an Ubuntu-based distribution developed to perform penetration tests and security assessments. It is designed to be fast and easy to use. It provides a minimal yet complete desktop environment, thanks to its own software repositories, which are always updated to the latest stable versions of the most often used and best-known ethical hacking tools.
- [Linux Kodachi](https://distrowatch.com/kodachi) (https://www.digi77.com/linux-kodachi/)
  Linux Kodachi is a Debian-based distribution which can be run from a DVD or USB thumb drive. The distribution filters all network traffic through a VPN and the Tor network, obscuring the user's network location. The distribution attempts to clean up after itself, removing traces of its use from the computer.
- [Zentyal Server](https://distrowatch.com/zentyal) (http://www.zentyal.org)
  Zentyal Server (formerly eBox Platform) is a commercial unified network server that offers easy and efficient computer network administration for small and medium-size businesses. It can act as a gateway, an infrastructure manager, a unified threat manager, an office server, a unified communication server or a combination of them. These functionalities are tightly integrated, automating most tasks, avoiding mistakes and saving time for system administrators. Zentyal is released under the GNU General Public License (GPL) and runs on top of Ubuntu.

It’s not on DistroWatch (yet), but another security and privacy aimend distro based on Ubuntu is:

- Discreete Linux (https://www.privacy-cd.org)
  Discreete Linux is an operating system with the special purpose of protecting data (more precisely: people) against surveillance attacks with trojan software.